Ability to see top saved questions and answers authored by a contributor
I spend a lot of time looking at the profile pages of top contributors, just to educate myself. I feel it would have been awesome to have the ability to see top saved questions and answers of a particular contributor. To be clear, I want to see the top posts of the contributor saved by other users.
To illustrate this further, this is how we see top questions and answers of a contributor:
Questions (we have Score, Activity, Newest, and Viewed tabs):

Answers (we have Score, Activity, and Newest tabs):

In both of these screens, what if we had a "Saved" tab to show what questions and answers of this contributor are the top favorites of users who have been saving the posts? In this view, it would be appropriate see the Saved counts as well.
Top saved answers would be more interesting compared to top saved questions.
Would this be of broad interest?

Badges based on Saved:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11220/favorite-answer
https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/11221/stellar-answer
https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/33/favorite-question
https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/36/stellar-question

Related (kind of a duplicate, but not really the same): Allow setting public visibility settings on saves lists, such as "public" and "unlisted" .

Saves was made private by design. It replaced the 'favorite' feature which was stored as a votetype in the stacl exchange data explorer and data-dump.

If it is private by design, why do we have badges based on number of saves a post gets?

Because someone saving your post indicates that you've written something they want to refer back to at some point in the future, which is an indication of decent quality and usefulness. You do not need to know who saved your post for the badge to mean something.

I don't want to know who all saved a post, I just want to know the top saved posts of a contributor which can be useful.

Oooohhhh... You want to know the posts authored by the user which have been saved the most times by other people. As this is written, I and it appears at least some of the other commenters, interpreted this request as "I want to see the top questions and answers which that user saved." Please [edit] to clarify which of those you are really wanting.

Yes, it does look like people misunderstood my intent. I have no interest in seeing what a given user is saving - there is almost no value in it and also it is being considered private.

Somewhat related: What does replacing bookmarks with Saves mean for SEDE?
